# Keras: class_weight for each training batch in fit_generator

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am using Keras for a segmentation problem. I use `fit_generator` for training my model. I am unsure how to use `class_weight` in case of `fit_generator`?
I actually want to calculate class weights for each batch and not the entire dataset. And I am unable to find a way to do this using `fit_generator` without duplication of effort.

I tried using a generator to return class_weight for each batch but that gives me

> TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

I also thought about using a customised callback to handle class weights. As per my knowledge, Keras callbacks need to be initialised with the training batches and labels. Is there a way that I can pass my training batches to a callback from within my `fit_generator` call?

Thanks.

Comment: A workaround would be to calculate the class_weights inside your network and add it as an output to your model. Then create a custom loss, where you can access it.

Comment: I can understand how I can calculate the class weights inside the model. Can you explain a bit more about the custom loss?